# Unable to connect to remote computer even though VPN connection is established

Tags: windows-7, networking, 64-bit, vpn, remote-access

I've installed, setup and connected across a VPN for work.

Now what? how do I connect to the remote computer?

I'm using Windows 7 64bit and trying to connect to Windows XP 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution ended up being two pronged:

One... the reason I sounded like a tard, was because I was. I was trying to RD into the SERVER, not the local IP (192.168.00.000)

Two... For some reason, when the screensaver kicks in or when the computer locks it disables the ability to RD/VNC in...

ended up adding a Scheduled Task > Batch file that does some cleaning (backups working directories), then logs off.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use remote desktop? Click `Start`, `Run`, type `mstsc` and then push `ENTER`. Type in the address of the computer you are trying to connect to.

Comment: I've tried RDC and VNC (Both used within) and neither connect... I'm wondering if maybe i just don't have sharing enabled on far computer